# Редактирование регулярного выражения PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется конструкция:

```
$string = "array('1', '2', '3', '4')";
```

Необходимо поочередно удалять по элементу. Частично решил с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
preg_replace("/'+.+\,/", '', $string, 1);
```

Суть в том, чтобы искать все что начинается с ' и заканчивается , . Однако, preg_replace ищет конечное вхождение символа, в итоге со строки остается только '4'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если только цифры, то так

```
'(\d+)',?
```

а если произвольные символы, то

```
'([^']+)',?
```

[демо](https://www.regex101.com/r/bH6lW6/1)

а если хотте именно удалять, то скобку надо передвинуть

```
('[^']+',?)
```

[демо](https://www.regex101.com/r/bH6lW6/2)

Answer (score 2):

Регулярные выражения по умолчанию при использовании таких квантификаторов как `+` ведут себя жадно. Встретив `.+` они стараются захватить столько символов, сколько смогут, при условии, что остальное выражение совпадет. Поэтому ваше выражение захватывает весь текст до последней запятой. Умерить пыл регулярных выражений, можно задав `?` после квантификатора и снизить таким образом жадность:

```
preg_replace("/'+.+?\,/", '', $string, 1);
```